# How to write math homework using latex?

Tags: paper

I usually sketch my homework on paper and then summarize the results in LaTeX because my professor downgrades for bad handwriting. In general, I write a more condensed answer in LaTeX than I write on paper because I'll use paper first so some steps are missing.

I can't think all my thoughts all in LaTeX and get rid of writing on paper and I can't turn in the huge mess I write on paper.

How do I include all detail in LaTeX that I wrote on paper without having to be bothered with rewriting and copying everything back and forth?

Comment: hard to say, some people just learn to type faster, straight to latex. But from paper one serious possibility is to scan and ocr the math with something like https://mathpix.com/ocr  I have no connection with them but I've tried their demos and latex it generates from images is pretty impressive

Comment: You can use TikZ or pstricks or even pict2e to do your images, but they are far more time consuming than using a compass and straight edge.  At least until you get a lot of practice.